# Python comparing DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Every 5 minutes I am gathering data from Yfinance (yahoo finance).
For 10 stocks I am gathering the stockprices and putting the list of stocks with the prices in a pd dataframe. I filter out the stocks that have changed more than 2% on the day and send them by email to me. What I want to do is not getting an email every 5 minutes but only in case the data in the dataframe has changed significantly.
So I want to know how to be able to store a dataframe and compare it with a new one that is created 5 minutes later.
Can someone help me here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide that much information about your application, but you could probably use something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

change_treshold = 0.02

def does_differ(frame, frame2):
    diff = abs((frame2 - frame) / frame)
    res = diff > change_treshold    
    return res.any()

frame = pd.DataFrame([2000, 300, 10000])
frame2 = pd.DataFrame([2001, 300, 9999])
frame3 = pd.DataFrame([2000, 270, 10000])

print(does_differ(frame, frame2))
print(does_differ(frame, frame3))
```